# Checking for Data Validation in Python

Tags: python

I'm building a program to calculate flight times. I've run into a bit of trouble and I can't seem to figure this out. Essentially, I have a dictionary that includes 6 states. I want to make sure the user inputs one of these states for the prompts. Otherwise, I want the program to keep asking the question until they input something valid. I came up with this, but it does not loop the question back.

```
cities = {"NY", "CA", "TX", "MA", "FL", "IL"}

def data_validator(var1, var2):
  while var1 not in var2:
    print("That's not valid. Use the state abbrevations from the list. \nFor example: for New York-- type NY")
    return

l = []
origin = input("What state are you flying from? Type the state abbreivation: ").upper()
data_validator(origin, cities)
l.append(origin)

destination = input("What state are you going to? Type the state abbreivation: ").upper()
print()
origin = origin.upper() 
data_validator(destination, cities)
l.append(destination)
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres a example of your code that will loop for input. It will ask for `origin` and if it is valid it will then ask for `destination`, then add if it valid to list. If one of the inputs is invalid it will start over so that may be something to think about, how to not start the loop over again but that is small thing for inputs.

```
def data_validator(var1, var2):
    if var1 not in var2:
        print("That's not valid. Use the state abbrevations from the list. \nFor example: for New York-- type NY")
        return False
    return True
    

l = []
while True:
    origin = input("What state are you flying from? Type the state abbreivation: ").upper()
    if data_validator(origin, cities) == True:
        #l.append(origin)

        destination = input("What state are you going to? Type the state abbreivation: ").upper()
        print()
        origin = origin.upper() 
        if data_validator(destination, cities) == True:
            l.append(origin)
            l.append(destination)
    print(l)
```

You May want to change the `data_validator` func to be false instead of true. `if var in var2:` Just so you don't add any automatically add an unwanted input.

```
if var in var2:
    return True
print("That's not valid. Use the state abbrevations from the list. \nFor example: for New York-- type NY")
return False
```

***************EDIT*************

```
def data_validator(var1, var2):
    if var1 in var2:
        return True
    print("That's not valid. Use the state abbrevations from the list. \nFor example: for New York-- type NY")
    return False
```

Forgot to add the list in top
`cities = {"NY", "CA", "TX", "MA", "FL", "IL"}`

Comment: okay, using your second suggestion the program does not recognize correct inputs

Comment: @HarperAvery Not sure what you mean, I have tested and it returns what is expected. i.e. input is  MA and FL it adds it to the list. I updated my answer with the full function updated.